# Read contents of multiple text files and print out specific line, in PHP

Tags: php, file, text

We have 300+ txt files, of which are basically replicates of an email, each txt file has the following format:

```
To: blabla@hotmail.com
Subject: blabla
From: bla1@hotmail.com
Message: Hello World!
```

The aim is to write a PHP script, which crawls through each file (all located within the same directory), and prints out a list of each 'unique' email address in the from field. The concept is very easy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? So far, I have managed to get my PHP script to read the contents of all of the files within the directory and output the result:

```
<?php
$directory = "emails/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('/n', $contents);
     echo '<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="4">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "<tr><td>$item</td></tr>\n";
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

So now, I need to be able to read and print line 3 of each of the files. I assume that its as simple as adding in array within the foreach loop to echo a specific line? I did try this, but synatctally, it's a bit of a mess:

```
<?php
$directory = "emails/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
**$lines = file($filename);**
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('/n', $contents);
     echo '<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="4">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       **echo "<tr><td>$lines[2]</td></tr>\n";**
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction here?

Comment: Can anyone else help at all??

Answer (score 0):

This is far easier to do with command line tools:

```
exec("grep '^From: ' *.txt|uniq", $output);
```

That'll return ONLY the lines that start with `From:` from all the text files. A simple substring extraction gets you the actual email address, and you've saved yourself a lot of PHP busywork.

Comment: What tool can I run this command in? I'm working on a Windows platform.

Comment: sure, as long as you've got grep and uniq installed (which are present on pretty much any linux/unix distribution).

Comment: Ah. well, you can use 'find' to accomplish some of this in windows. not sure what'd you use for uniq though.

Comment: hmm. little confused now. I understand that its much easier using a direct statement in Linux, however I am working on an XAMMP (Apache) instance through Windows. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: You can still exec in windows php. you just need to find a windows equivalent of grep, which is a far far more powerful version of 'find'.