# PHP script to print a specific value next to a string, from multiple text files in same directory?

Tags: php, file

I have 50 txt files, of which are basically replicates of an email, each txt file has the following format:

```
To: blabla@examplecom 
Subject: blabla 
From: bla1@example.com 
Message: This is a test message
```

The aim is to write a PHP script, which crawls through each file (all located within the same directory), and prints out a list of each 'unique' email address in the from field. The concept is very easy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? So far, I have managed to get my PHP script to read the contents of all of the files within the directory and output the result:

```
<?php
$directory = "emails/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('/n', $contents);
     echo '<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="4">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "<tr><td>$item</td></tr>\n";
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

So now, I need to be able to retrieve the value assigned next to the 'From: ' string from each file, then displaying the output of that value, in a list.

Can anyone push me in the right direction here? Any code explanations would be beneficial, as I understand the concept and what I need to do, but syntactically I am struggling!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read contents of multiple text files and print out specific line, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178540/read-contents-of-multiple-text-files-and-print-out-specific-line-in-php)

Comment: Apologies, it is based on the question but with a different solution needed, I have re-edited the question, with the changes for the new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> $to = stristr($item, 'To: ');
>   $from = stristr($item, 'From: ');
>   $subject = stristr($item, 'Subject: ');
>   $message = stristr($item, 'Message: ');
>   if($to !== FALSE) echo $to;
>   elseif($from !== FALSE) echo $from;
>   elseif($subject !== FALSE) echo $subject;
>   elseif($message !== FALSE) echo $message;

This will get the values you are looking for. Just put this inside the foreach loop.